# Sending Emails with Django using local server is successful. When uploading to heroku it failed

Tags: python, django, email, heroku

So my team is using Django built-in function to send emails to users with gmail accounts, and it worked on my local server. My team deployed our Django app on Heroku before and it also worked. However, I have redesigned and thus re-deployed my Django app with a clear database (but without changing email functionality), and I am not receiving any email this time.

Would it be possible that this fails gmail authentication, or I have to adjust some settings on my computer, because I downloaded the previous work on GitHub?

Comment: You have to use some addon like [Mailgun](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mailgun)

Comment: Thx. But previously it worked and I am not sure if they used mailgun or sendgrid or anything. Are you suggesting that I can look after these addons locally?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too and as `afilardo` suggested you should use [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) in order to send and receive emails.

I did not install the [Heroku's Mailgun plugin](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mailgun) in my Django project, although. It did worked perfectly without it.

All I had to do was to follow [this](http://thingsilearned.com/2011/06/07/mailgun-as-an-smtp-server-for-django-apps/) small how-to guide and upgrade my account to Mailgun (by simply entering credit card info). Then, create some SMTP accounts (through Mailgun) and you are ready to go.

Keep in mind though that you will have to redirect traffic of these custom SMTP addresses to another address (say, a Gmail one) in order to read them. Mailgun does not provide a graphical email inbox.